How to create files in directories using File System API
I'm trying to write files to a Volume using the File System API using the following code:
const fileHandle = await this.directoryHandle?.getFileHandle(
  entry.filename,
  {
    create: true,
  }
);

... write file with writable

It's working fine with sample files (e.g. test.txt) but not with files like test/test.txt which should be written in a new directory. I'm getting the following error:
Failed to execute 'getFileHandle' on 'FileSystemDirectoryHandle': Name is not allowed

How can I create files in directories using the File System API? I don't want to create a new directoryHandle for each new folder though.

You need to create the subdirectory with getDirectoryHandle(), and then write files to that:
dir = await showDirectoryPicker({ mode: "readwrite" });
subdir = await dir.getDirectoryHandle("subdir", { create: true });
file = await subdir.getFileHandle("myfile.txt", { create: true });


I don't want to create a new directoryHandle for each new folder

This is apparently not possible.
You can only write files via their immediate parent directory's handle, not across multiple directories with paths such as subDir/myfile.txt.
